# Mathematical Logic and Analysis. About boundaries and complement sets

Tags: analysis, logic

May you check if this answer is correct? Can you help me with my doubts? I think that I am cheating in the last steps...

$ \partial$ is the boundary of the set.

*[image: Here is the problem:]*

Here is my new solution:

$ (\partial$ $ (A \cap B) \cap (\partial B)^C)$ $\cup$ $(\partial$ $ (A \cap B) \cap A^C) = $

$ Empty Set $ $\cup$ $ (\partial$ $ (A \cap B) \cap A^C) = $

$ \partial$ $ (A \cap B) \cap A^C  $

***Case 1:***

Set A is closed. Then we have the empty set that is a subset of every set.

***Case 2:***

Set A is open. Then the result is

$ \partial$ $ (A \cap B) - $ $\partial B$ that is a subset of $ \partial A$

***Case 3:***

A part of A, in the boundary, is open and another part is closed, but it is also  a subset of $ \partial A$

Comment: For the record: this symbol is not delta, in MathJax you can write it using \partial.

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If you apply De Morgan's initially, you get $(A \cap \partial B)^c$ istead of $(A \cup \partial B)^c$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Thank you so much!